# Continuity of function $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n}$

Tags: calculus

I try find the values of $f(x)$, $f(x)=0$ si $|x|<1,$ $f(1)=0.5$ and $f(x)=1,$ if $|x|>1$. But I cannot prove this.

Comment: You may want to check that.  Also, what about it can you not prove?

Comment: Just check the continuity of lim 1+x^n . It fails. This is just continuity of lim x^n. There is a discontinuity at x=1. Since division is continuous, the composition is discontinuous at x=1.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^n}=$$

- $\frac{1}{2}$ if $x=1$
- $1$ if $|x|<1$
- $0$ if $|x|>1$
- doesn't exist if $x=-1$

thus, $(f_n)_n $ has a pointwise limit at $(-\infty,-1)\cup (-1,+\infty)$ which is not  continuous at $x=1$.